# Detect a change to a paticular element of a model in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want it so that if the users edit the membership number or the role then pushes save that particular row gets post requested to my API,

http://plnkr.co/edit/plM45Ulwl2zKLFdPsKPl?p=preview

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users" id="{{ user.userId}}">
    ..
    <td>{{ user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{ user.email}}</td>
    <td ng-click="editMemNo = !editMemNo" ng-show="editMemNo">
       {{ user.role}}  
    </td>
    ..
   <button> Save</button>
 ..
</tr>

angular.module("userList", []).controller("usersCtrl", function($scope) {

  var original = [{
    "userId": "1",
    "memNo": "1",
    "name": "asdf",
    "username": "max",
    "email": "max@gmail.com",
    "role": "10",
    "mobile": "079951334"
  },

  ..

  }];

  $scope.users = angular.copy(original);
  $scope.original = angular.copy(original);

  $scope.editMemNo = false;

  $scope.editMemNo = function() {
    $scope.editMemNo = true;
  };

  $scope.roles = ["1", "2", "9", "10"];
```

Basically I want to add a ng-click to the button, so that when I click it it will post only that row, to the database on the condition it has been altered (i.e. a dirty state). So I could add a function, something like

```
$scope.submitRow = function( the row I want  ){

     $http.post bla bla

};
```

and in the button i would have

```
 <button ng-click="sumbitRow(What do I put here?)"
```

So I think basically my question is what do I stick in the submitRow parameters from the ng-click? and or is the best way to do what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use $scope.$watch, it allows you to observe one particular property of an object and bind a callback to that event.

http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/controllers/responding-to-scope-changes.html

Edit: I read the question again. It's still a bit unclear what you're asking for, but to get the differences in the objects try this:
https://github.com/flitbit/diff

Comment: Yes maybe my question is a bit unclear I will edit it now, I actually was looking at flitbit, as I believed that would enable me to diffs on the objects and only  perfrom essential database transactions,

Answer (score 0):

I kind of done it now, I feel stupid now

For the button...

```
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="pushRow($index)">
```

For the code...

```
$scope.pushRow = function($index){

    alert( "Lets say that we have posted this to the database " + JSON.stringify( $scope.users[$index] ));

};
```